# Splitting and then removing last character in comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a comprehension in python to split a string and then remove the last character in each of the elements in the resulting list, for example:

```
>>> text = "firstX secondY thirdZ"
>>> split_text = < some code >
>>> print(split_text)
['first','second','third']
```

I can get it to do what I want without a comprehension:

```
>>> text = "firstX secondY thirdZ"
>>> split_text = []
>>> for temp in text.split():
...     split_text.append(temp[:-1])
... 
>>> print(split_text)
['first', 'second', 'third']
```

but I would like to learn how to do it in a single comprehension..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
text = "firstX secondY thirdZ"
text_lst = [x[:-1] for x in text.split(' ')]
print(text_lst)
```

output

```
['first', 'second', 'third']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
splittext = [x[:-1] for x in text.split()]
```